# How to configure additional dashboards like at nemo.sonarqube.org

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

There are nice dashboards being used at http://nemo.sonarqube.org

- Helicopter View
- Languages Panel
- Activity

How can I realize them in my installation? Do I need some plugins for instance?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I need this, is that right.

http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/

Comment: Yes indeed, the aggregation feature as displayed on the public Nemo instance is provided by the commercial portfolio management plugin (Views).

Comment: Plus one for the username.